# What is wrong with this Google Sheet formula?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working on a Google Sheet to use for stock trading and I want to have a cell that checks (W% equal or higher than L%) AND (L% equal or lower than 33%). I thought this formula would work but it doesnt, any idea what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: AND is also formula and should be used like this IF(AND(E9 >= E11; E11 <= 0,33); "Y", "N")

Answer (score 0):

IFS() rather than a simple IF() is the function to use. IFS() with AND evaluates multiple conditions and returns a value that corresponds to the first true condition.

[reference](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/how-to-correctly-use-and-or-functions-with-ifs-in-google-sheets/)

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is using `AND` the wrong way

Google Sheets has an `AND` funtion. It is used as `AND(E9 >= E11; E11 <= 0,33)`

The final formula is `IF(AND(E9 >= E11; E11 <= 0,33); "Y"; "N")`.

Another way is by using the following formula:

```
IF(N(E9 >= E11) * N(E11 <= 0,33); "Y"; "N")
```

As `N` parses `TRUE` as `1` and `FALSE` as `0` and `IF` parases `1` as `TRUE` and `0` as `FALSE`.

Comment: Another way is by using the IFS function as was mentionen in a [previous answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/146463/88163)